# opencv was not found in the pkg-config

Tags: cmake, opencv, pkg-config

Using `cmake` and `cuda` i create `opencv` , the file was saved in

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.8/cv2.so
```

now i'm trying to install `darknet` but i got this error

Package `opencv` was not found in the `pkg-config` search path.

Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc`
to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable

```
No package 'opencv' found
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, you installed it manually from source. It should declared `.pc` file in one of the directories or through environment variable.

`man pkg-config`

```
pkg-config retrieves information about packages from  special  metadata
       files.  These  files  are named after the package, and has a .pc exten‐
       sion.   On  most  systems,  pkg-config  looks  in   /usr/lib/pkgconfig,
       /usr/share/pkgconfig,     /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig     and     /usr/lo‐
       cal/share/pkgconfig for these files.  It will additionally look in  the
       colon-separated  (on  Windows, semicolon-separated) list of directories
       specified by the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable.
```

Just make sure you have installed opencv not just copied its shared lib to python. I expect default installation put `.pc` file in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/`

Comment: i didn't found opencv.pc in any directory but i wrote a simple code to make sure that opencv is working and it run fine

python3 
import cv2
cv2.__version__
4.5.0

Comment: what i did simply is install ubuntu 20.04 , cuda , cudnn ,cmake and pulled a opencv repo and its examps and make it .